# Show control depending on object data in XtraGrid Column

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I need to show control depending on object data in XtraGrid cell of column. i.e. different coltrol in cell depending on data. Any tutorial or demo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `CustomRowCellEdit` event.